# iOS5 Storyboard persistent UI across scenes

Tags: ios5, uistoryboard

I'm just starting with iOS development. Currently focused on iPad.

I would like to persist a few UI elements across (and on top of) several scenes in a storyboard.

What is the best way to do this? Put the persistent elements in a separate view/xib and load that in each of the ViewControllers for each scene? Or is there a way I can just have one instance of the persistent elements?

Happy to elaborate if needed...

Cheers

Comment: solved by dynamically creating UI in appdelegate / loading Views/VCs into tabbarcontrol root, hiding default tab bar, and managing z order

Comment: So did you end up not really using the storyboard or do you still manage to maintain the storyboard usage?

Comment: kept the storyboard, just created the persistent UI in the app delegate and added it to the root subview